# Como executar comandos Python dentro do cmd usando um script

Tags: python, cmd, terminal

Quero criar um executável que abra um cmd e depois disso, insira uma função clear() automaticamente para que possa limpar a tela sempre que necessário apenas digitando clear().
Fiz:

```
import os

os.system('python')
```

Assim ele abre o python no cmd, mas depois disso não consigo mais rodar nenhuma linha rodando esse script.

Como posso escrever a função clear() dentro desse terminal python que acabou de abrir usando esse mesmo script, de forma que, quando execute o script, o terminal abra configurado com a função clear e pronto para uso rápido do python?

```
def clear():
 os.system('cls')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*E se você fizer o contrário?*

Você não precisa iniciar o interpretador Python a partir de um programa só para inserir uma função nele na marra e depois assumir o controle.

É mais fácil iniciar o interpretador normalmente, usando o comando `python` e **deixar que ele se vire para encontrar e compilar a sua função** (ou funções).

Isso é semelhante a um arquivo de inicialização do shell Linux, como `.bash_profile`. O que estiver no arquivo vai ser executado sempre que você abrir o shell.

**Como fazer isso em Python?**

Configurando a variável de ambiente `PYTHONSTARTUP` para apontar para o arquivo com extensão `.py` onde está a sua função.

Por exemplo, você pode criar o arquivo `.pythonstartup.py` na sua pasta de usuário com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
import os

def clear():
    os.system('cls')
```

Depois é só configurar a variável de ambiente nas propriedades do sistema ou direto na linha de comando:

```
set PYTHONSTARTUP=%userprofile%/.pythonstartup.py
```

Assim, toda vez que você iniciar o interpretador Python, a função `clear()` vai estar disponível. Você também pode adicionar outras funções úteis nesse arquivo.

Comment: Ficou perfeito! Obrigado mesmo